# Upper-bounding a sum over non-identity permutations

Tags: summation, finite-groups, permutations, symmetric-groups, quantum-groups

**EDIT:** Question 1 has been settled (below). The bounty is for question 2.

Let $n\geq 3$ and consider the following function $f:S_n\backslash\{e\}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

$$f(\sigma)=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^{i+\sigma(i)}}}$$

where $\sigma\in S_n$ is considered a function $\sigma:\{1,\dots,n\}\rightarrow \{1,\dots,n\}.$

I believe $f$ is maximised at $\sigma=(n-1\quad n)$ where it takes on the value

$$f(\sigma)=\frac{1}{n^{3n-1}}\frac{n^n-1}{n-1}.$$

> 1. Prove this assertion.

Secondly I am interested in upper-bounding the sum for $k\in \mathbb{N}$:

$$\frac{1}{4n^{2k(n-2)}}\sum_{\sigma\in S_n\backslash{e}}f(\sigma)^{2k},$$

particularly in the asymptotic case $n\rightarrow \infty$ and $k=k(n)\rightarrow \infty$.

> 2. Any bounds that are "significantly" better than using the trivial
>      $$\sum_{j=1}^N|a_j|\leq N\cdot \max_j|a_j|.$$

**Context:**

These sums are related to bounding the distance to random of the random walk on the quantum group $\widehat{S_n}$ (given by $F(\widehat{S_n})=\mathbb{C}S_n$) driven by a state (positive definite function on $G$) $u\in M_p(\widehat{S_n})$ given by the permutation representation together with the unit vector $\alpha=(\alpha_i)$ where
$$\alpha_i=\sqrt{n^{n-i}\frac{n-1}{n^n-1}}.$$

Comment: First assertion can be proved similarly to the rearrangement inequality (i.e. the proof on wikipedia) by considering your series to be the termwise product of two series.  The descent step in that proof produces a permutation with one or two more fixed points than the prior one, so the optimal non-identity permutation must be a transposition.  It shouldn't be hard to show the one you give is the best possibility.

Comment: Err, after looking again it might not be quite that simple... Leaving the post up in case it's still helpful :/

Comment: Cheers... I am trying to salvage that idea at the moment.

Comment: OK, as I understand there is a way to remove inversions and increase the sum... and one inversion is removed at a time... just before getting to the identity one has an adjacent transposition... therefore I just have to prove that $(n-1\quad n)$ is the maximising transposition.

Comment: @LanceSackless yup got assertion 1 anyway.

Comment: Perhaps I am missing something - didn't get too much sleep last night, so I am inclined to believe the fault lies with me - but for $\sigma = ( n - 1 \quad n )$, doesn't the $i = 1$ term in $f(\sigma)$ alone give a lower bound of $\frac{1}{n}$?  The value claimed is more like $\frac{1}{n^{2n}}$.

Comment: @Shagnik thank you I will have another look at that value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding question 2, one can improve on the trivial bound a bit, but I'm not sure this counts as "significant".

Let $f_0 = \max_{\sigma \neq e} f(\sigma)$.  As you noted, $\frac{n! - 1}{4n^{2k(n-2)}} f_0^{2k}$ is a trivial upper bound.  For the sake of later comparison, let us call this trivial bound $M_0$.

Now observe that $f_0 \approx \frac{1}{n}$.  Moreover, $f(\sigma) \approx \frac{1}{n}$ if and only if $\sigma(1) = 1$, and $f(\sigma) = O \left( n^{-\frac32} \right)$ otherwise (this order of magnitude is attained if either $\sigma(1) = 2$ or $\sigma(2) = 1$).

That is to say, only $(n-1)! - 1$ non-identity permutations come close to the maximum value, and for the remaining permutations, $f(\sigma)$ is smaller by a factor of $n^{\frac12}$.  Using the trivial bound on these two sets of permutations separately, we have
$$ \frac{1}{4n^{2k(n-2)}} \sum_{\sigma \in S_n \setminus \{e \}} f(\sigma)^{2k} \lessapprox \frac{(n-1)!-1}{4n^{2k(n-2)}} f_0^{2k} + \frac{n! - (n-1)!}{4n^{2k(n-2)}} \left( f_0 n^{-\frac12} \right)^{2k} \sim \left( n^{-1} + n^{-k} \right) M_0.$$

Hence this new upper bound is only a factor $n$ smaller than the trivial one.  However, we cannot hope to do much better*:
$$ \frac{1}{4n^{2k(n-2)}} \sum_{\sigma \in S_n \setminus \{e \}} f(\sigma)^{2k} \ge \frac{1}{4n^{2k(n-2)}} \sum_{\substack{\sigma \in S_n \setminus \{ e \} \\ \sigma(1) = 1}} f(\sigma)^{2k} \ge \frac{(n-1)! - 1}{4n^{2k(n-2)}} \cdot \frac{1}{n^{2k}} \gtrapprox \frac{(n-1)! - 1}{4n^{2k(n-2)}} f_0^{2k} \sim \frac{1}{n} M_0.$$

[*The approximation in the second line (the $\gtrapprox$) is only valid when $k$ does not grow too quickly with $n$.  $f_0 = \frac{1}{n} + O(n^{-2})$, and if $k$ is linear in $n$, then $f_0^{2k}$ can be much larger than $\frac{1}{n^{2k}}$.]

I've used asymptotic approximations here just to avoid having to be too careful and fiddling around with constants.  However, it shouldn't be too hard to turn these into bona fide bounds: $f_0$ is essentially a rapidly converging geometric series.

Comment: This is lovely thank you.

Comment: Happy to help, this was fun!

Comment: Yes I don't know what I was at with the $f_0$... it is straightforward to prove $f_0= S(n-1\quad n)\leq S(e)\leq \frac{1}{n-1}$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a proof of the first assertion.

Let $a_i$ be an increasing or decreasing sequence. For a permutation $\sigma\in S_n$, consider the sum

$$S(\sigma)=\sum_{i=1}^na_ia_{\sigma(i)}.$$

An *inversion* is a pair $(j,k)\subset\{1,\dots,n\}$ with $j<k$ and $\sigma(j)>\sigma(k)$. All non-identity permutations have at least one inversion. Take the minimum inversion $(j^*,k^*)$ (with respect to the lexicographic order) $(j,k)$ and define a new permutation by

$$\tau_1(i):=(j^*\quad k^*)\sigma(i)=\begin{cases}\sigma(i)&\text{ if }i\neq j,k\\ \sigma(j)&\text{ if } i=k\\ \sigma(k)&\text{ if }i=j\end{cases}.$$

The calculation on [page 79](https://books.google.ie/books?id=GDRIBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA79&lpg=PA79&dq=rearrangement%20inequality%20non%20identity%20permutations&source=bl&ots=7E__BKF5Tv&sig=-mntpCEGNLqzzKoeUUyHGbwf3FU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiYxIDRzoTOAhURM8AKHX9OCjgQ6AEIVzAJ#v=onepage&q=rearrangement%20inequality%20non%20identity%20permutations&f=false) shows that

$$S(\sigma)\leq S(\tau_1).$$

This process of multiplying by suitably chosen transpositions strictly reduces the number of inversions and can always be done until $\tau_r=e$. Furthermore each multiplication increases the sum.

Therefore, no matter what the starting permutation $\sigma$, $\displaystyle\tau_{r-1}$ is a transposition and therefore to maximise $S$ on $S_n\backslash\{e\}$ one just maximises over transpositions.

Now consider the decreasing sequence $\displaystyle a_i=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^i}}$. 
Define $$f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^x}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^{x+1}}}.$$
Note $f(x)$ is positive for $x\geq 1$. Furthermore
$$f'(x)=-\frac{1}{2}\ln n\cdot f(x),$$
and so $f(x)$ --- the one-step differences between the $a_i$ --- is decreasing and so the smallest one-step difference is between $a_{n-1}$ and $a_n$.

Let $(j\quad k)$ be a permutation with $j<k$. Note from the result about the one-step difference and $a_k\leq a_{j+1}$

$$
\begin{align*}
a_{n-1}-a_n&\leq a_{j}-a_{j+1}\leq a_{j}-a_k
\\ \Rightarrow (a_{n-1}-a_n)^2&\leq (a_j-a_k)^2
\\ \Rightarrow a_ja_k+a_ka_j+a_{n-1}^2+a_n^2&\leq a_j^2+a_k^2+a_na_{n-1}+a_{n-1}a_n
\\\Rightarrow S((j \quad k))&\leq S((n-1\quad n))\,\,\bullet
\end{align*}$$

This proof can be generalised to:

> Suppose that $\{a_i\}_{i=1}^n$ is a decreasing sequence such that the one-step difference is minimised for $a_{j+1}-a_j$. Then $S:S_n\backslash \{e\}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is maximised at $(j\quad j+1)$.

It might be possible to generalise it to two sequences a lá the [Rearrangement Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rearrangement_inequality).